# A word or phrase to describe a plan that helps people achieve their goals?

Tags: phrase-requests

I've created an online web form.

The web form has a step-by-step guide which asks the user to provide a detailed answer for each question.

Once the user has finished the form their feedback will be arranged in a final overview document which they can use as a plan to share with others and help them reach their goal.

What is this called? Did I just answer my own question? Thanks for humoring me.

Comment: I don't disagree that a plan is a plan...

Comment: Are the plans strictly professional? If so, I might add *action* to your *plan* to make [*action plan*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_plan), defined by WP to be: "a detailed plan outlining actions needed to reach one or more goals." And sharing an action plan with others is emphasized in the article. Those and the other uses I've seen are related to business or politics. But I think it's still OK if the plan had personal goals.

Comment: This would be strictly professional so 'action plan' does feel apropos. I'm going to run with that for now unless anyone else would like to chime in.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could use ***roadmap***?

Answer (score 2):

How about calling it a ***game plan***?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Answers on StackExchange are expected to be authoritative on their own, and should provide a detailed explanation and such references and examples as may be appropriate. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: @choster: Thanks for the welcome. I have already taken the site tour and reviewed the help center. Should I infer from your comment that you believe my answer is somehow not "appropriate"? The questioner asked for suggested names for something he described. I offered such a suggestion. What more needs to be said?

Comment: Fuller explanations are preferred to one-word answers. Why *game plan*? What does it mean, and how does it address the question at hand? What are some examples of how it can be used? What is its origin, and is there a dictionary or other reference where it can be found? This helps both the original poster and subsequent visitors understand how suitable the answer is, and that it is not just one person's opinion.

Comment: I realize you may be following the example of the other answers here, and it is not my intention to pick on you or single you out. Your answer, being recent, was flagged and appeared in the review queue; had I reviewed the other answers when they were given six months ago, I would have offered similar advice.

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to explain. Ordinarily, I would certainly provide the sort of answer you describe; in this case, however, I think a short suggestion is all the questioner wanted.

Answer (score -1):

sounds like you could call it an Agenda